# Can the C language forget a variable?

Tags: c, gdb, gnu

It sounds very weird, but I noticed that my program crashes because a variable is literally forgotten (turning to 0).

This is the output of gdb

```
...
709         while (progressione->avanti !=  NULL) {
(gdb) p nGiocatori 
$30 = 4
(gdb) step
713         lista_stanze[i] = *progressione; // aggiungo la stanza alla 
lista
(gdb) p nGiocatori 
$31 = 4
(gdb) step
731         puts("");
(gdb) p nGiocatori 
$32 = 0
(gdb)
```

as you can see after *puts("")* the value of *nGiocatori* is turned to 0.
The problem is not related to *puts("")* whatever statement in replace of *puts("")* causes the same problem.

Can anyone explain to me why this strange thing happens?

(I don't know if it matters or not, but the variable nGiocatori is global and static unsigned short, its value is taken through scanf.)

Comment: Just looking at that, I have no idea what could be happening. But it seems interesting. Can you provide a [minimal and reproducible example so we can take a look at it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without it there is no way to understand what is happening

Comment: C doesn't forget global variables. But they can be changed unexpectedly by bugs. Posting the code (see above) will help us help you.

Comment: I would not rule out ' lista_stanze[i] = *progressione;' out-of-bounds write, especially if compiled  with optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I noticed that my program crashes because a variable is literally forgotten

It's not "forgotten" it's overwritten.

Sounds like you have a global buffer overflow in your program. Several general approaches can help you:

- turn on all compiler warnings and make sure your code doesn't produce any (for GCC, use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`)
- build your program with address sanitizer (`gcc -fsanitize=address ...`)
- set a GDB watchpoint on the variable, and observe *where* exactly it is being overwritten